# Troubles converting Awk command to script

Tags: bash, awk

I found a couple of useful commands over at http://centoshelp.org/security/securing-sshd/
Namely, the two that parse /var/log/secure to check attacked accounts/attacking IPs
I would really love to convert them to a simpler command that I can run with su, rather than trying to remember them.
I've tried shell scripts as well as a direct awk script, but I always get various errors, usually to do with the single quotations it seems, sometimes syntax though (depending on what combination of double quotes and single quotes I use or omit).

```
awk 'gsub(".*sshd.*Failed password for (invalid user )?", "") {print $1}' /var/log/secure* | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -5

awk 'gsub(".*sshd.*Failed password for (invalid user )?", "") {print $3}' /var/log/secure* | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -5
```

I can't seem to get the combination right, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Always surround anything that should be ignored by the shell, such as your snippet of awk code, in single quotes. Single-quoted text is not treated in any special way by the shell. Double quoted text is interpolated, however, so you have to be careful there.

Comment: It wwould be helpful if you said what the errors were for each example.

Comment: Ahh, well, surround the entire piece of code in single quotes provides this; top5accounts.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `".*sshd.*Failed password for (invalid user )?",'

Comment: @FizzBuzz: Your command as posted looks fine to me as is, I don't understand where your error comes from. Please tell me you are not enclosing one of the above lines in quotes!

Comment: @Sorpigal: Nope, but I'm trying to put it in something like a shell script and just dumping it in a .sh file (i.e. "#!/bin/sh" newline above code) keeps producing errors, no matter what I try...Just running it from the command line is fine though, so yeah, I'm confused.

Comment: @FizzBuzz: How are you saving it to a file? Are you sure your line endings are correct? What is the file encoding?

Comment: Why are you adding more quotes? That's not the correct thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to convert something to a simple command when it can't be further simplified directly is to create a script or function. Put the former in a directory in your `PATH` or the latter in a file such as `~/bin/functions` which you source from your `~/.bashrc`.

Sometimes this isn't possible or practical, but something like [AutoKey](http://code.google.com/p/autokey/) can enter it for you from a shortcut you designate without the need to memorize the full command.

Comment: Yes I know...that's the whole point of my question. I want to go from those huge commands to something like "sh top5accounts.sh"

Comment: @FizzBuzz: Save one of the commands exactly as shown in your question with no additional quotes in a file of that name and you're done. You could also make the first line be `#!/bin/bash` and do `chmod u+x top5accounts` and you'll be able to run the script without putting `sh` at the beginning. It's recommended that you not use `.sh` at the end of your script names. Later, if you rewrite a script in another language, it won't make sense if it's called `foo.sh`.

Comment: Aaaand apparently I've been derping this whole time...Tried making it into a .sh file with #!/bin/sh for the first line and it worked -_- My bad!